# Modifying a file in-place inside nested for loops

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, in-place

I am iterating directories and files inside of them while I modify in place each file. I am looking to have the **new modified** file being read right after.
Here is my code with descriptive comments:

```
# go through each directory based on their ids
for id in id_list:
    id_dir = os.path.join(ouput_dir, id)
    os.chdir(id_dir)

    # go through all files (with a specific extension)
    for filename in glob('*' + ext):

        # modify the file by replacing all new-line characters with an empty space
        with fileinput.FileInput(filename, inplace=True) as f:
            for line in f:
                print(line.replace('\n', ' '), end='')

        # here I would like to read the NEW modified file
        with open(filename) as newf:
            content = newf.read()
```

As it stands, the `newf` is **not** the new modified one, but instead the original `f`. I think I understand why that is, however I found it difficult to overcome that issue.

I can always do 2 separate iterations (go through each directory based on their ids, go through all files (with a specific extension) and modify the file, and then repeat iteration to read each one of them) but I was hoping if there was a more efficient way around it. Perhaps if it would be possible to *restart* the second `for` loop after the modification has taken place and then have the `read` take place (so to avoid at least repeating the outer `for` loop).

Any ideas/designs of to achieve the above with a clean and efficient way?

Comment: you only ever print the replaced value, you never change it. `line.replace()` returns a new instance of a line and would not overwrite the original?

Comment: @TheLazyScripter I corrected a small typo just now. Besides that, the chunk of code that performs the replace works OK; i.e. if I try it separately it modifies and saves in-place the file.

Comment: Have you tried replacing `print(line.replace('\n', ' '), end='')` with `line = line.replace('\n', ' '); print(line);` ?

Comment: Have you tried saving the file with `f.write()` and `f.close()` at the end of `for line in f:` loop?

Comment: @JanZeiseweis No, it does not work. Plus, I don't understand what the extra `print` statement does.

Comment: Can't reproduce... for me this code does what you want it to do.

Comment: @MaxiMai Tried it, no difference. Besides, if I am not mistaken, the `with` statement in my code handles the file when finished and closes it.

Comment: @Yannis sorry, I wasn't aware, that the `print()` is actually aplying the changes to the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me it works with this code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os
from glob import glob
import fileinput

id_list=['1']
ouput_dir='.'
ext = '.txt'
# go through each directory based on their ids
for id in id_list:
    id_dir = os.path.join(ouput_dir, id)
    os.chdir(id_dir)

    # go through all files (with a specific extension)
    for filename in glob('*' + ext):

        # modify the file by replacing all new-line characters with an empty space
        for line in  fileinput.FileInput(filename, inplace=True):
            print(line.replace('\n', ' ') , end="")

        # here I would like to read the NEW modified file
        with open(filename) as newf:
            content = newf.read()
        print(content)
```

notice how I iterate over the lines!

Answer (score 1):

I am not saying that the way you are going about doing this is incorrect but I feel that you are overcomplicating it. Here is my super simple solution.

```
import glob, fileinput
for filename in glob('*' + ext):

    f_in = (x.rstrip() for x in open(filename, 'rb').readlines()) #instead of trying to modify in place we instead read in data and replace raw_values.
    with open(filename, 'wb') as f_out: # we then write the data stream back out     
    #extra modification to the data can go here, i just remove the /r and /n and write back out
        for i in f_in:
            f_out.write(i)

    #now there is no need to read the data back in because we already have a static referance to it.
```